# Power supply replacement question

Tags: power-supply

I need to replace a power supply on a machine. My current power supply has an input of 120v~60Hz 12VA, can i replace it for one with an input of 120V~60Hz 25W?

Comment: You haven't told us the output specs, they matter too.

Comment: 9v 1.2A. It's the same for both power supplies.

Comment: Be aware that power supplies have a minimum load to guarantee regulation.  For a 25W supply you may need to have a few watts load for the output not to go out of spec.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, unless it's a very inefficient power supply (under 50%). VA is the Volts times the Amps output, Watts is the Volts times the Amps input. That's being jargon correct though. These days lazy manufacturers quote watts when they mean VA anyway. Try it and see how hot it gets, if it seems too hot switch it off before the smoke escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, as long as the output voltage of the new supply is the same as the old one.  I'd expect the rated output current to be about twice the old supply's rating, but your machine will only draw the current it requires.